# Throttle rendering of element for v-for loop in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, v-for

Is there a way in vuejs to have a functionality similar to that of  [polymer dom-repeat initial count](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/api/elements/dom-repeat#DomRepeat-property-initialCount)'s initial count which renders items in batches.

I want to render a list complex object but UI waits for all the elements to be created and mounted and then displays all at once.

Creation of element is time consuming because it registers a lot of events and watchers.

Is there a default way to do it or any other way I can throttle the elements?

Answer (score 0):

Vue doesn't support this, and this isn't really something suitable for userland code.

How many items are you rendering? Hundreds? Thousands?

Have you benchmarked your code to see what is causing the slowdown – is it Vue's rendering code that is slow or maybe your component has a complex render function and/or complex `created()` code? Make sure you're setting `key` on each item to make re-renders quicker.

Alternative solutions:

- Only render a subset of items and incrementally render more as the user scrolls down. You'll need some kind of infinite scroll component to help you achieve this (check GitHub or implement it yourself).
- Use a virtualized list component to render only the visible items, [vue-virtual-scroller](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller) is one such implementation.

Comment: Rendering item count is between 50-80. Its not much. But the component has a lot of reactive fields. 
While reviewing the performance, scripting is taking a lot of time compared to rendering. 
Function stack is just filled with following methods - createElm, createChildren, Vue._update, Vue._render, init, watcher, get, Vue.$mount. None of these methods are defined by user, all are vue's. All I have is a few getters to display the data